# How do I change the number in an array name based on the variable i in a for loop?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, swift2, variable-names

I am trying to, through standard input, get arrays of numbers. this is what the input looks like:

```
3
11 2 4
4 5 6
10 8 -12
```

The top number is the integer `N`, the rows of numbers are arrays. `N` represents `N` numbers in each of the `N` arrays. I want to get each array, and assign it. The thing is, I might not know how many arrays there are. So far, I have this:

```
var n = Int(readLine()!)!

var arr: [String] = []

for i in 0..<n {
    if readLine()! == "\n" || arr.count == 0 {
        var arr1 = readLine()!.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)
        arr.append(arr1)
    }
}

var firstDiag = 0
var secondDiag = 0

for i in 0..<n {
    firstDiag += Int(arr[i][i])!
    secondDiag += Int(arr[i][n-i-1])!
}


let dif = firstDiag - secondDiag

print(abs(dif))
```

What I want to change is the variable in the first for loop. Instead of `arr1`, I want to create an array that is based of of the variable `i` for that for-loop, like `arr<i>`, so I have an array of arrays like this:

```
var arr = [arr0, arr1, arr2]
```

And so on.

Is there a way to do this in quote, "basic Swift" (whatever that means to you)?

Comment: Your code does not compile. But if you change the first line to `var arr: [[String]] = []` then it already gives you an array of arrays.

Comment: @MartinR, I know it doesn't compile, I'll fix that when I figure out how to use stdin with a playground. But how do I give each array in the array a different name?

Comment: You cannot create variables at runtime, and you don't need it. All that you want is an array of arrays and your code – with that small modification – already does that.